# Select one of multiple connected networks for outgoing requests in Mac Catalyst

Tags: swift, macos, networking, mac-catalyst

I have a Mac-Catalyst application with an outgoing network call that I want to ensure is sent over a particular network, and thus not sent over any other possibly connected networks.

Is there an Apple API to detect multiple connected networks and choose one for an outgoing request?